# Beginning SQL group by and AVG

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull information from two columns titled clientstate and clientrevenue in my table. I want clientstate to show up as the state, and have only distinct names in it, and under client revenue I want the average revenue per state, and that will only show up if there are at least two clients from that state. I am very new at this, so what I have is pretty iffy:

```
SELECT clientstate, clientrevenue
FROM client
GROUP BY clientrevenue
HAVING COUNT (*) >=2;
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT clientstate AS [State]
     , AVG(clientrevenue) AS [Average Revenue]
FROM client
GROUP BY clientstate
```

Comment: When I write that the error "your query does not include the specified expression 'clientstate' as part of an aggregate function. What does that mean?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One other part, how do I get it to only pull the states that have at least two clients?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by ClientRevenue will try to group similar values and that doesn't have a logical sense.

First, in order to get distinct states, clientstate column needs to be used in the GROUP BY statement.

Thus, the code would be  :

```
SELECT clientstate, AVG(clientrevenue)
FROM Source_Table
GROUP BY clientstate --this would get you distinct states
```

Now, considering the 2 clients per state, it's rather a condition than a HAVING statement. HAVING statement limits your query results according to the aggregate function you are using. For instance, in the code aforementioned, the aggregate function is AVG(clientrevenue). So, we can only use it in HAVING. we can not add count(*) unless it was used in SELECT.

So, you need to add it as a condition like

```
SELECT clientstate, AVG(clientrevenue)
FROM Source_Table A
WHERE (SELECT count(DISTINCT client_ID) FROM Source_Table B  
        WHERE A.clientstate = B.clientstate) >= 2 --Condition
GROUP BY clientstate --this would get you distinct states
```